# Unity JSON: Is there a way if the player goes to the save file, and corrupts the file, a way to detect that?

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, save, loading

In my project, I have the player info being saved out to a JSON file. I am encrypting the information before I save it but if the player goes into the file and happens to delete one character of the file, when the game loads, because it depends upon that file, the game freezes up. I do have it so that a new player info is created if no file is detected, but if the file is there and they mess with it, is there any way of detecting that and correcting it before the game tries to load it. I am using JSONUtility built into Unity.

Comment: Just try/catch the error and handle it like and other IO operations?

Comment: Use PlayerPrefs to save, it goes a bit down in the folders so it is not so easy to find. You can save as binary and maybe even encrypt so it is eve harder on the player to do something. If the user screws the file, then your code is not safe enough. You should have checks if parsing went fine and so on. Ultimate solution, store info on server if you can. Nowadays, games save data on server as it allows safer process and analytics.

Comment: You could use md5 fingerprint to check if the data is correct. Save the fingerprint in the PlayerPrefs or in another location. Anyway if they mess the file by editing in  purpose why would you care?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a try/catch when loading the JSON file

```
        try
    {
        JsonUtility.FromJSON(...)
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        Print("The file was not found: '{e}'");
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
    {
        Print("The directory was not found: '{e}'");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Print("The file could not be opened: '{e}'");
    }
```

However, this shouldn't be that important. If a player is trying to mess with the game files and you are worried about the program crashing, you shouldn't because that player shouldn't have been editing game files.

Comment: I did end up going with a try catch to resolve the issue. Yeah I would hope that the player doesnt attempt to change the file but I was just looking for a fail safe in case the player did.

Answer (score 0):

I think using both hashing and try/catch checking would be the better solution
You can just try to open the file then compare its hash with the hash you saved in the last game session:

```
private void LoadSave()
{
    try
    {
        JsonUtility.FromJson("filename", ...);
        string oldHash = PlayerPrefs.GetString("importantSaveFileHash");
        string newHash = CalculateMd5("filename");
        if (oldHash == null || oldHash == newHash)
        {
            //recalculate hash every time you change the save file
            //you can also encrypt this hash for better security
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("importantSaveFileHash", newHash); 
            //RESULT: Save file is cool!
        }
        else
        {
            //RESULT: Save file was modified!
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //RESULT: broken file
    }
}

private static string CalculateMd5(string filename)
{
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
        {
            var hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
            return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
        }
    }
}
```

Btw you can just use PlayerPrefs to store all the game state (I know that sometimes its important to have visible and readable save file) - choose what you need)

**UPD**: its not good to store game state in PlayerPrefs - use any another way instead (read comments)

Comment: No, do not save things in PlayerPrefs! Stopit! Player Prefs was never intended to hold game state, as it had a limited size, limited allowable data types, and is unsecured.

Comment: You are right, it's not good but Its just a simple workaround for the serverless game. As for me I would never secure offline game state, its useless)

Comment: Just because its useless to secure offline game state is not a reason to use a system that was never meant for saving game state.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html says: "Stores and accesses player preferences between game sessions." So, yeah, my fault, preference != game state.

Comment: Bingo. It means things like "volume level" "input schema (mouse or keyboard?)" Etc. Things the program should remember from session to session, but are independent from game state.